# DBX Error: Driver could not be properly initialized

Tags: c++builder, mysql-connector, dbexpress, libmysql

> DBX Error: Driver could not be properly initialized. Client library may be missing, not installed properly, of the wrong version, or the driver may be missing from the system path..

The above error occurs when attempting to open SQL window (right-clicking MySQLConnection in Data Explorer panel) or when attempting to open a connection in code (compiled app) by executing Open() method on a TSQLConnection object.

Tried placing libmysql.dll and libmysqld.dll in Windows\System32, Windows\SysWOW64, and in project\Win32\debug. Tested with both 32- and 64-bit versions of the DLLs.

What am I missing?

Tool chain:
Windows 10 64 bit,
Embarcadero® C++Builder 10.2 Version 25.0.31059.3231 (Community Edition),
MySQL 5.7.16 64 bit

Comment: Update: Tested with FireDAC using TFDConnection object. In design mode, with 32-bit libmysql.dll in Windows\SysWOW, setting Connected to true, no error. However, attempting to access by (right)clicking MySQL under FireDAC/MySQL Server in Data Explorer panel yields "[FireDAC][Stan][Def]-254. Definition [MySQL] is not found in [C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\FireDAC\FDConnectionDefs.ini]."